# Stuff function is producing multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a bit of a long-shot but i'm hoping someone can help me get the stuff function working. I'm getting the correct data back but its on multiple lines. I can't get the suff function to place the DaysWithoutLogout onto one line.

**UPDATE**: Okay, I've simplified my issue but i'm not really understanding the STUFF function. I've seen lots of examples of on this site that select from one table but not multiple. My select is still returning multiple rows, not two as expected.

```
Create table #DaysWithoutLoggout
(
    userid int,
    [days] nvarchar(max)

)

create table #user
(
    userid int,
    name nvarchar(100)
)

Insert into #user values('1', 'nick')
Insert into #user values('2', 'jon')

Insert into #DaysWithoutLoggout values('1', '13')
Insert into #DaysWithoutLoggout values('1', '15')
Insert into #DaysWithoutLoggout values('1', '24')
Insert into #DaysWithoutLoggout values('2', '10')
Insert into #DaysWithoutLoggout values('2', '3')

select us.name, alldays = 
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + b.[days]
           FROM #DaysWithoutLoggout b 
           inner join #user u
           on u.userid = b.userid
           WHERE b.[days] = a.[days]
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM #DaysWithoutLoggout a
inner join #user us
           on us.userid = a.userid
GROUP BY us.name, a.[days]
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data?  Are you completely certain that your main query returns only a single row per user?  I don't see a GROUP BY ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample table and data, you should be able to concatenate the `days` together using the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT us.name,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + d.days
          FROM DaysWithoutLoggout d
          WHERE d.userid = us.userid
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS days
FROM [user] us;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52c80/7)